Как внутри партиции сделать ранг так, чтобы у одинаковых значений были одинаковые ранги. Но при этом работал счетчик?
Есть таблица «"DataBase1".Table1» в которой по временным интервалам (Start_DT – End_DT) содержится разнообразная информация по клиентам (в том числе и их канал обслуживания).  Из этой таблицы нужно выбрать все данные (пример запроса ниже) и еще один расчетный столбец «Key» с возрастающим ключом, который увеличивается для каждого Клиента при каждой смене канала его обслуживания.
Пример базового запроса к задаче 1:
SELECT
  CLIENT_ID, START_DT, END_DT, CHANNEL, «ваш текст» AS KEY
FROM
  "DataBase1".Table1
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND CLIENT_ID IN(123, 124)
ORDER BY
  CLIENT_ID, START_DT DESC

Пример выгрузки к задаче 1:



CLIENT_ID
START_DT
END_DT
CHANNEL
KEY




124
17.11.18
31.12.99
Массовый
1


124
10.10.18
16.11.18
Массовый
1


123
13.11.18
31.12.99
Массовый
3


123
12.11.18
12.11.18
Премьер
2


123
08.11.18
11.11.18
Массовый
1


123
13.10.18
07.11.18
Массовый
1



Т.е. внутри партиции CLIENT_ID нужен счетчик, который считает каждую смену канала. При этом выводится как дополнительное поле в данном SELECT.
Пробовала сделать оконной функцией DENSE_RANK()
SELECT CLIENT_ID, START_DT, END_DT, CHANNEL,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY channel)
FROM table1
ORDER BY client_id DESC, start_dt DESC;

Вывод такой:



CLIENT_ID
START_DT
END_DT
CHANNEL
KEY




124
17.11.18
31.12.99
Массовый
1


124
10.10.18
16.11.18
Массовый
1


123
13.11.18
31.12.99
Массовый
1


123
12.11.18
12.11.18
Премьер
2


123
08.11.18
11.11.18
Массовый
1


123
13.10.18
07.11.18
Массовый
1




Похоже предполагается, что диапазоны (Start_dt-End_dt) не пересекаются? Вам нужно зафиксировать смену канала в порядке, определяемом диапазоном (start_dt, к примеру) с использованием функции LAG или LEAD. Затем просуммировать эти смены нарастающим порядком. Задача типа GAPS and ISLANDS.

Посмотрите пример



client_id
start_dt
end_dt
channel
chkey




124
2018-11-17
1999-12-31
Массовый
1


124
2018-10-10
2018-11-16
Массовый
1


123
2018-11-13
1999-12-31
Массовый
3


123
2018-11-12
2018-11-12
Премьер
2


123
2018-11-08
2018-11-11
Массовый
1


123
2018-10-13
2018-11-07
Массовый
1



select *
  ,sum(isChange)over(partition by client_id order by start_dt)+1 key
from(
select *
  ,case when channel=lag(channel,1,channel)over(partition by client_id order by start_dt)
     then 0
   else 1
   end isChange
from Table1
)a
order by client_id desc,start_dt desc




client_id
start_dt
end_dt
channel
chkey
ischange
key




124
2018-11-17
1999-12-31
Массовый
1
0
1


124
2018-10-10
2018-11-16
Массовый
1
0
1


123
2018-11-13
1999-12-31
Массовый
3
1
3


123
2018-11-12
2018-11-12
Премьер
2
1
2


123
2018-11-08
2018-11-11
Массовый
1
0
1


123
2018-10-13
2018-11-07
Массовый
1
0
1



fiddle
